# Deezer API Search does not honor the "order" and sometimes return weird results?

Tags: api, deezer

I am trying to search tracks on deezer, using the API, in all my test I always end with and unsorted list and sometimes with results that not match my query.

Does someone know how to make sorted search work?

---

As an example: A query for all the tracks with "feo" and ordered by TRACK_ASC as follows:

`curl -s 'https://api.deezer.com/search/trackorder=TRACK_ASC&q=track:feo&limit=10' | jq '.data[] | .title'`

It is returning:

`"Feo"
"Feo, fuerte y formal"
"Nanga Ti Feo"
"Nanga Ti Feo"
"Nanga Ti Feo"
"El Bueno, El Malo Y El Feo (The Good, The Bad & The Ugly) (Dance Hall Version) (Feat. Tego Calderón And Eddie Dee)"
"El Bueno, El Malo y El Feo (The Good, The Bad & The Ugly) (Reggaeton Remix) (Feat. Tego Calderón And Eddie Dee) (Reggaeton Remix; Feat. Tego Calderón And Eddie Dee)"
"El Feo"
"Esta To Feo"
"Lo Feo"`

That is missing the order a little bit!

Answer (score 2):

The order param is not currently implementing for advanced search; that's why it is not considered on your request.

This should be available soon.

Comment: Will be great if that is explained in the API Documentation!

Do you know when order support will be available for advanced search?

Comment: We are about to release an APP that use Deezer advanced search. Do you have any idea on when ORDER will be supported?